# Number formatting a CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have developed a script that produces a CSV file. On inspection of the file, some cell's are being interpreted not the way I want..

E.g In my list in python, values that are '02e4' are being automatically formatted to be 2.00E+04.

```
table = [['aa02', 'fb4a82', '0a0009'], ['02e4, '452ca2', '0b0004']]


ofile = open('test.csv', 'wb')
for i in range(0, len(table)):
     for j in range(0, len(table[i]):
           ofile.write(table[i][j] + ",")
     ofile.write("\n")
```

This gives me:

```
aa02         fb4a82    0a0009
2.00E+04     452ca2    0b0004
```

I've tried using the csv.writer instead where `writer = csv.writer(ofile, ...)`
and giving attributes from the lib (e.g csv.QUOTE_ALL)... but its the same output as before..

Is there a way using the CSV lib to automatically format all my values as strings before it's written?

Or is this not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the quoting parameter in your csv writer to `csv.QUOTE_ALL`. 
See the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for more info:

```
import csv
with open('myfile.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    wtr = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wtr.writerow(...)
```

Although it sounds like the problem might lie with your csv viewer. Excel has a rather annoying habit of auto-formatting data like you describe.

Comment: Its not working.. tried:                                                                        
           table = [['ee02', 'ffsssd'], ['02e4', '00009']]


with open('myfile.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for i in range(0, len(table)):
        for j in range(0, len(table[i])):
            csvfile.write(table[i][j] + ",")
        csvfile.write("\n")                                                                                                              Its producing 02e4 still as 2.00E+04

Comment: Code segments like that don't work in comments, you should instead edit your question with your attempt. But the problem is that you're not writing to the file with the csv writer. Instead of `csvfile.write(...)`, use `writer.writerow()`. Read the documentation I linked to.

Comment: I tried with writer.writerow() too and the output is exactly the same :(

Comment: Can you edit your question with more details? What format are the values? Are they strings to start with? Exactly what code are you running? What are you using to view the resulting CSV?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the '02e4' to show up in excel as "02e4" then annoyingly you have to write a csv with triple-double quotes: """02e4""". I don't know of a way to do this with the csv writer because it limits your quote character to a character. However, you can do something similar to your original attempt:

```
table = [['aa02', 'fb4a82', '0a0009'], ['02e4', '452ca2', '0b0004']]

ofile = open('test.csv', 'wb')
for i in range(0, len(table)):
     for j in range(len(table[i])):
           ofile.write('"""%s""",'%table[i][j])
     ofile.write("\n")
```

If opened in a text editor your csv file will read:

```
"""aa02""","""fb4a82""","""0a0009""",
"""02e4""","""452ca2""","""0b0004""",
```

This produces the following result in Excel:

[image: Excel Double Quote Example Image]

If you wanted to use any single character quotation you could use the csv module like so:

```
import csv

table = [['aa02', 'fb4a82', '0a0009'], ['02e4', '452ca2', '0b0004']]
ofile = open('test.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for i in range(len(table)):
    writer.writerow(table[i])
```

The output in the text editor will be:

```
|aa02|,|fb4a82|,|0a0009|
|02e4|,|452ca2|,|0b0004|
```

and Excel will show:

[image: Excel Pipe Quote Example Image]